# My question is being upvoted, but not the accepted (right) answer

Tags: discussion, voting, upvotes

I do not have a problem, just some curiosity.

I posted a question a while ago and recently it was correctly answered. I upvoted and accepted this answer.

Since then, my question was upvoted a couple of times, but no *reward* was given to a member who provided the right answer. It makes me curious what causes this behavior?

I always assumed that late upvotes to a question are the result of someone experiencing the same (or similar) problem, searching for the answer and discovering that someone already had this very problem and posted the question. But if they need the answer and there it is ready for consumption, why not to upvote it?

I understand that this is kind of a psychological question, but hopefully someone already considered such a situation and came to some conclusion.

---

I would like to provide **additional** information to narrow down my case.

I did indeed posted a detailed question (with screen captures and such). It boiled down to the following: I tried to install a certain plug-in for the very latest version of a popular IDE and ran into a problem. I downloaded the plugin from a usual place and followed the normal routine.

The answer was that for the latest version of the IDE, the plugin needs to be downloaded from a different (special) directory in the same widely accepted domain.

I did just that and the problem was solved. So it was **the** right answer.

Comment: Sometimes I have a problem someone else has had too. I see a question about that and I upvote it. Then I see the answers and they don't solve my problem - even the accepted one. I leave those untouched. Happens more often than not.

Comment: First, anybody can face the same problem, but the answer may not solve everybody's problem, or doesn't seem useful for them. Second, it might be because of your well-formed question that they upvoted!

Comment: I may run into a question about a problem that I *once* had. Maybe I made the problem moot by completely changing my approach. (I'm not talking about finding a *solution* to the problem but avoiding the problem completely *in the first place*. Simple example: "How can I represent 'any date' in a date field?". Then I restructure my app for some other reason and my need for 'any date' disappears.) So I can readily evaluate the question as a useful one. However, since I've not solved the problem when I encountered it I can't be sure the answers are actually right. So I don't vote on them.

Comment: Don't assume the answer that works for you works for everybody else too.

Comment: When I open a question, the voting buttons are right there at the top of the page, so I vote. The voting buttons for answers are all the way at the bottom...I have to move my mouse, or for particularly long questions, scroll. Too much effort, next question. I'm of course being facetious; there's no way to know why some people might vote on a question but not the corresponding answer, so you're merely inviting idle speculation.

Comment: If a question is highly upvoted, but the answer is not, it may spark others to post another answer that will get the same attention as the question.

Comment: You could ask [Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) why he never upvotes ;)

Comment: when there's a game to be played, people play the game and try to game the game. it makes them feel good.

Comment: Sometimes I just find a topic interesting, and the question *well-written*, so that I give it an upvote, but none of the answers satisfy my *quality* standards (even if their solutions are *correct*)

Comment: Though I purposefully didn't post a direct link to the post, I understand that with minimal sleuthing it's identity can be established. Some kind souls did upvote the answer.  I would like to ask you a favor, if you do go through the trouble and reach the post, **please** kindly do **not** upvote the question itself.

Answer (score 34):

> I did just that and the problem was solved. So it was the **right** answer.

It may be the right answer to **your** question, but not the right answer to who reaches your question.

From your clarification:

> I did indeed posted a detailed question (with screen captures and such). It boiled down to the following: I tried to install a certain plug-in for the very latest version of a popular IDE and ran into a problem. I downloaded the plugin from a usual place and followed the normal routine.

You've wrote a detailed tutorial on how to install a plugin normally. It is very plausible that this was what a good part of googlers were looking for. It looks like they weren't facing the same issue as you, they just wanted to know how to install the plugin.

Comment: This is also a big part of SO. Answers are not the only thing that can help people. Some questions are so well written that they can be seen as an example workflow among other things.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Some questions, because they explain a problem so well, can be used as answers to other questions.  E.g., when someone asks "why doesn't X work?" sometimes a question asking "I know that X doesn't work, and here's the explanation of why from the documentation, so what's the workaround?" is the best answer.

Comment: To expand on what Fabricio pointed out.. On SO especially, selected answers can often be too specific, not optimal, etc. Popular questions draw a lot of attention, so even years after the question was asked, folks will still post answers that are more optimized or more relevant (libraries and such are always being updated) than the selected one. I generally always upvote a question that leads me to an answer, which may or may not be the *selected* answer.

Answer (score 11):

Multiple scenarios are possible. The most ridiculous one would be:

**Farm for the Electorate badge,** because it is a safe bet if the question already has a positive score and an accepted answer. Not many will get suspicious if something like this happens.

**The answer looks fishy especially with a non-standard link.** Some voters don't want to vote on something that might infect the machine. It is totally understandable that some simply don't want to risk this by trying out the answer...

**Answers that depend on stuff behind links need to be executed to assert that it actually works and warrants an upvote.**

Like [Renan said in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272640/my-question-is-being-upvoted-but-not-the-accepted-right-answer?cb=1#comment100555_272640) **Maybe the answer simply didn't solve the problem for somebody else but only for you.**

Comment: Based on your answer I added yet additional clarification.  The answer pointed out that plug-in's publisher put the version of the plugin compatible with the latest version of the IDE in a separate directory. So the link was to the same trusted site.

Comment: Are you saying that they see a "nice" question and upvote it right away (since the button is right there), but do not know whether the answer is correct until they try it.  So they follow the link and when they install the right plug-in, they consider the problem solved and do not bother to come back and acknowledge the answer?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that, but it is a totally valid reason. My examples basically boil down to *Question are sometimes more easily   to assert that they are useful*.

Answer (score 10):

The answerer made a fairly elementary mistake, one that you didn't make.  You documented your question well, included pretty screen-shots and wrote sufficient text, but not too much.  Anybody that googles your question can see in an instant that, yes, that's my problem too!

The answer is severely lacking in that regard.  The only possible way to find out that it is indeed correct is to go off site, download the update, lose 10 minutes of your life with your fingers crossed.  The odds that the googler will go back to vote the post helpful are low.

SO users demand more from an answer, at minimum a way to verify that the answer applies to them.  Easy enough to do with by including, say, the specific version number of the add-in that has this problem.  Or a link to a bug database entry that documents the problem, preferably copy/pasted so it doesn't require a trip off-site.

That's work, hard to find fault with the answerer not wanting to take the time.  His post is unlikely to have lasting value, I personally just post a comment instead.  But that's for everybody to decide by themselves.

Comment: When I answer someone's question (be it a full-blown answer or a comment), I try do it on their level (I do not care about the posterity at that time).  The more advanced the inquirer *seems* to be the more laconic answer I post and vice versa.  I believe that my question showed that I knew what I was doing, so the unambiguous point into the right direction was all I needed.  If the answer would go into too much of detail it would've confused me, since it would've signaled that I missed something on the basic level,

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, multiple scenarios are possible: (Some of them come from a pessimistic view on life, but being able to identify with others is just one aspect of my good nature.)

- There is a while between reading the question and testing the answer; you simply may have forgotten about upvoting the answer too.
- The answer turned out to be basic or rudimental.
- You do not like the answerer, for whatever reason.
- You like the questioner, for whatever reason.
- You self are the answerer.
- The answer has a rather extensive edit history, whereby credits would go to the wrong person.
- The answer is controversial, possibly according to the comments.
- Your vote on the question can no longer be undone.
- The question just deserved an upvote because of its clarity, style, research effort, owner's reputation, etc...
- You have hit the dayly vote limit.

Comment: As long as most of the above are not *your* reasons to upvote only the answer. Some of those are *nasty*

Comment: @owl That thought is exactly the thing I tried to prevent with the bit between parenthesis. Though _nasty_, they form an answer to the question being asked. It's not that I want to give people excuses for not voting. For the record: I only vote for content. E.g. in my favorite tag there's a person of who's never ceasing presence and dominant commenting style I dislike, but I keep upvoting his/her posts simply because they are so damn well-writen, to the point, or insightfull, and often all of that combined.

Comment: Yeah, same thing here - although I'm myself probably the dominator for crypto related questions :) Sometimes it is *hard* to stay objective towards the answers though. Many good reasons here, upvoted.