# Answering questions and not upvoting the question, please explain that

Tags: discussion, questions, upvotes

Can someone explain the thinking behind answering a question and not voting the question up?  Or even voting up an answer and not the question?

I can see this happening occasionally, but I see it all the time.

Why do people deem a question worthy of answering but not upvoting?

Just as an arbitrary example: [JavaScript Regex to capture repeating part of decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26363390/javascript-regex-to-capture-repeating-part-of-decimal/26363819#26363819)

---

**Edit**

Woo Momma.  Why the downvotes?  Interesting.

I personally (intend to) always upvote a question I've answered.  Just was curious why others don't.

Comment: Sometimes (oftentimes) the question quality is just.. meh. Not enough research, for example. Not worthy of downvoting, but not upvoting either. That doesn't make such a post *answerable*. Why equate the two?

Comment: A question worth answering isn't always a question worthy of an upvote.

Comment: I can have a quick answer to a question without deeming the question worthy of an upvote.

Comment: The example you gave. I wouldn't upvote it simply because the op hasn't shown any attempt at solving it on his/her own. On the surface it looks like a "i can haz codes" question. (though that's pretty typical with regexp questions)

Comment: If you're trying to imply that you think you deserve upvotes from everyone who answered that question of yours... this probably isn't going to work out the way you hope.

Comment: Are you asking questions because you want answers, or because you want upvotes?

Comment: The real question is: Why do people keep answering questions they don't feel are worthy of upvoting? And the answer is simple: Rep whoring. (Just to not be misunderstood, I'm as guilty of that as anyone else)

Comment: @Yannis I think you're discounting the feeling from knowing that your answer may actually be helping others.

Comment: @Yannis, what about actually helping others? Don't judge others based on your standards and behaviour.

Comment: @Yannis: This happens in reality all the time. Someone vomits a question that is really uninformed and slangy, yet a good teacher may tell a great answer.

Comment: @walther What about it? Why is helping one person - especially one that didn't bother doing any effort solving their own problem - more important than helping a community of developers? Spoon feeding doesn't have any positives, however you might spin it. The only thing you gain by answering questions that don't show any prior effort is legitimizing laziness.

Answer (score 17):

Why *should* questions always be upvoted when answering, or when upvoting an answer? Neither the fact that an question is answerable nor the fact that an answer is upvote-worthy means that the question itself is worthy of an upvote.

Comment: or up-voting an answer and down-voting a question like I did here?

Answer (score 3):

> I personally (intend to) always upvote a question I've answered. Just
>   was curious why others don't.

And what is the reasoning behind this? Mark the question as "good", because you were able to answer it? That doesn't make any sense. It's like asking "hey, why don't you answer the question you've upvoted?".

To be honest, you shouldn't upvote any question you ever answer, because you might be encouraging `meh` questions. People then don't understand the difference and it seems you don't either.

Comment: +1 On the first paragraph, but the second sounds like generalization.

Answer (score 2):

The best reason to upvote a question is not because you feel a sense of social obligation. It is because the question was helpful to you, and this frequently means that you would have asked it yourself if the other person hadn't already.

When answering a question you are pretty unlikely to need the answer yourself. It could happen but probably not often. As such, your upvote would be purely social and less motivated than a vote of genuine gratitude. That seems optional.

Comment: Being useful doesn't necessarily mean that use is scoped to you, it could mean that the question was going to be useful to a broader audience as well, in which case it would make sense to upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's draw a parallel. We'll start by assuming there are two separate things at play: (1) the quality of the question/amount of research that went into it, and (2) how answerable it is.

Let's assume I'm a waiter. I have a lot of control over how much attention I pay to the table: do I answer questions, and provide a lot of detail about today's specials? Am I attentive, and know what I'm talking about? Or do I just come up to the table and say "go ahead". Think of that as the quality of the question, and the amount of research.

But - the waiter has no control over the food coming out of the kitchen. It may impact his tips, or it may not. The tip is supposed to reflect the quality of the wait staff, not the quality of the food. Just because I ate the food, doesn't mean that I think the waiter did a subpar or an excellent job.

Likewise, just because I answer a question, it doesn't mean that I think it deserves an upvote. I might upvote it anyway, even if the question wasn't asked very well, just because it's a REALLY interesting and unexplored topic. In the same way, I might tip a waiter, despite his shoddy service, just because the food was phenomenal.

Just because the two functions CAN impact each other does not mean that they WILL impact each other.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple scenarios are possible:

- You really like helping people: it gives pride and satisfaction.
- You like the question and want to learn or experiment on giving the answer: maybe it turned out to be not thát challenging after all.
- You do not like the questioner, for whatever reason.
- You like the answerer, for whatever reason.
- The question has a rather extensive edit history, whereby credits would go to the "wrong" person.
- You answer in order to gain reputation.
- The answer outstands the question in style, brevity, clarity, completeness, grammar, research effort, etc.
- The answer gave more than the question asked for, but is still relevant.
- Your vote on the answer or question can no longer be undone.
- You have hit the daily vote limit.

See also the reverse situation: [My question is being upvoted, but not the accepted (right) answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272640/757830).