# Portuguese notification on SO

Tags: bug, notifications

I got a badge notification for a [recent answer on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274450) and it was in Portuguese instead of English:

[image: Screenshot of Portuguese notification on English SO]

Comment: We are invading SO with cybernetic man-o-war's and claiming it for the Iberian Peninsula! (just kidding)

Comment: Related: [Chinese badge notification](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242141/167646)

Comment: Portuguese power :D

Comment: @Stijn it was actually japanese :D

Comment: It's not only notifications - my [SO] badge page now show two "Esclarecido" badges. IIUC, these are supposed to be "Enlightened" badges. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/19/enlightened?userid=2422776).

Comment: This issue happened in July... http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234589

Comment: @StevenV I don't think it's exactly the same. I don't have an account on Pt.SO and I definitely hadn't visited that site within weeks of this happening. Probably related though.

Comment: The OP in the MSE question didn't have a pt.so account either, so I think it's the same issue. But the resolution may not be the same. I'd still suspect caching to be the root cause though.

Comment: I see, the answer on that is saying that two different users were involved and one user's activities apparently polluted the cache for a different user.